# Flutter and dart Vscode Insider and not inside will rise up this proble?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
```

When User try to open the app or debug the dart code this will show user.

Comment: something isn't setup correctly regarding the gradle wrapper.. have a look at the "Let’s have a look at the following project layout to illustrate the expected Wrapper files" section [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:adding_wrapper) (the error could mean you don't have a `gradle-wrapper.jar`)